# Can not get in order TS with forwardRef in React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have component which so far was used as functional one like this (thunk is "any" temporarily for simplicity)

```
interface Props {
    thunkFetchMovies: any;
}


const SearchInput = (props:Props) => {
    const { thunkFetchMovies } = props;

return (
        <div className="TopBar__center">
            <div className="search">
            </div>
        </div>)
}
```

Due to need of modifying DIV with className 'search' I try to rewrite the component with forwardRef. Have already checked few suggestions from websites, but nothing works as expected.
Tried to follow these sources:
https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-generic-forward-refs/
https://www.carlrippon.com/react-forwardref-typescript/

as well as few similar questions here, but it does not work as expected. How should I type it?

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify the css you don't need the ref of the element in the Dom.

You can edit the class name based on props, for example:

```
<button className={props.foo == "bar" ? "search":""} />
```